# Creating upper and lower bound slopes to a linear equation statistically

Tags: vba, excel, statistics, excel-charts

The following graph represents my dataset, it is change in strain (y axis) and change in temperature (x axis)

[image]

As you can see it is a linear relationship, I am wanting to create upper and lower bound thresholds in a robust statistical manner. Below are some attempts.

[image]

[image]

These are both based on 99% confidence levels but as you can see there are data points which lie well and truly outside this range, this is concerning as this means the upper and lower bounds of this linear equation are just too small, due to the majority of the data set lying well within the curves. I am developing an alarm system which will show "fail" whenever the strain readings jump outside these linear slopes. What I am asking is if there is any other way of statistically producing upper and lower bound curves outside of normal distribution confidence levels, as my methods will sound an alarm all to often!

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can calculate the upper and lower curve as follows;

1. Use the LINEST(y_data,x_data,TRUE,TRUE) function to fit your data (with stats=TRUE to return regression statistics
2. LINEST will return a 5 row by 2 column table, which contains:
   `m`      `b`
   `SEm`    `SEb`
   `R2`     `SEy`
   `F`      `DOF`
   `SSreg` `SSres`
3. The curves are calculated with the equation:

   =y0 +/- TINV(alpha, DOF) * SQRT(SEy^2/N + SEm^2*(x0-xavg)^2)

In the above equation:
`x0` is any x-value
`xavg` is the average of your xdata (calculate with AVG function)
`y0 = m*x0 + b`
`N` is the number of data points
`DOF` is the degrees of freedom (LINEST returns this)
`SEy` is the standard error returned by LINEST
`SEm` is the standard error of the slope (returned by LINEST)
`alpha` is 1 minus desired confidence level
`TINV` is Excel's function for calculating t-statistics
`+/-` do this calculation twice for each x0: once with + to get the upper curve, once with - to get the lower curve

Plot the two curves you generate vs x.

Also, check out the Analysis Toolpak --- it may provide a more automated way to do confidence intervals.

Hope that helps